# How do I output an inline transription of a hexdump to ACSII?

Tags: linux, ascii, hexdump

Here's an example from a program called HEXedit, which show's what I mean by inline:

```
3a40 - 31 65 33 38 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 1e38............
3a50 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 00 74 00 65 00 - ............t.e.
3a60 - 78 00 74 00 2f 00 61 00 73 00 63 00 69 00 69 00 - x.t./.a.s.c.i.i.
3a70 - 00 00 18 00 61 00 66 00 66 00 79 00 6d 00 65 00 - ....a.f.f.y.m.e
3a80 - 74 00 72 00 69 00 78 00 2d 00 61 00 72 00 72 00 - t.r.i.x.-.a.r.r
3a90 - 61 00 79 00 2d 00 62 00 61 00 72 00 63 00 6f 00 - a.y.-.b.a.r.c.o.
3aa0 - 64 00 65 00 00 00 64 00 40 00 35 00 32 00 30 00 - d.e...d.@.5.2.0.
3ab0 - 38 00 32 00 36 00 30 00 30 00 39 00 31 00 30 00 - 8.2.6.0.0.9.1.0.
3ac0 - 37 00 30 00 36 00 31 00 31 00 31 00 38 00 31 00 - 7.0.6.1.1.1.8.1.
3ad0 - 31 00 34 00 31 00 32 00 31 00 33 00 34 00 35 00 - 1.4.1.2.1.3.4.5.
3ae0 - 35 00 30 00 39 00 38 00 39 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 5.0.9.8.9.......
3af0 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
3b00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0a 00 - ................
```

Possible there's a way to do this via [hexdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm), but I haven't found a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `hexdump -C`.

```
$ hexdump -C end
00000000  54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20  74 68 65 20 65 6e 64 0a  |This is the end.|
00000010  42 65 61 75 74 69 66 75  6c 20 66 72 69 65 6e 64  |Beautiful friend|
00000020  0a                                                |.|
00000021
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
od -x -c
```

For a slightly different presentation

Comment: Interesting, is that only ASCII -- or something else too?

Comment: afaik, presents each byt in hexa and its ascii repesentation under